# Identification of $W$ and $Z$ mass terms in SSB and Unitary Gauge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, higgs, symmetry-breaking, electroweak

I have two questions, both relating to the SSB of Electroweak Lagrangian.

My notes say that after breaking and expanding around the VEV, the masses of $W$ and $Z$ are identified by comparing to the lagrangian

$$ L = m_{w}W^+_\mu W^{-\mu} +  {\frac{1}{2}}mZZ.    $$

My first question is why the factor of half for the case of the $Z$ bosons mass?

My other question is how the transformation to the unitary gauge

$$ \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{0}{v + H(x)}) $$ explicitly works, as in what does the transformation from the complex Higgs Doublet actually look like. Most texts I can find just state it, but I'm not sure how the process works.

Comment: The first question (v2) is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525913/2451

Comment: Thanks @Qmechanic, so from this can I interpret the factor 1/2 associated with a real field, also arising for a complex field but is absorbed in the definition of it (the factor of $\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: You are completely and unequivocally comfortable with the [abelian case](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism#Spontaneous_breaking_of_a_local_gauge_symmetry) and cannot generalize it to the non-abelian one? Several good texts *do* detail it.